# TypeError: db.collection(...).aggregate(...).cursor is not a function when querying Mongo in batches

Tags: mongodb

I have a pretty large Mongo collection which I want to query in batches of 50K docs using a cursor with a pre-defined batchSize.

This is my code-

```
const aggregation = [{ $match: { example: '1' }}]

await mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
const db = mongoose.connection
db.collection('some-collection')
    .aggregate(aggregation)
    .cursor({ batchSize: 50000 })
    .exec()

await cursor.eachAsync(async (doc) => {
  // do something
})
```

For some reason I keep getting the following error -

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).aggregate(...).cursor is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to query Mongo in batches?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no `.cursor()` function. You should specify batch size in the `options` parametr of `.aggregate()`.

```
const aggregation = [{ $match: { example: '1' }}]

await mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
const db = mongoose.connection
const cursor = db.collection('some-collection')
    .aggregate(aggregation, { cursor: { batchSize: 50000 } })

await cursor.eachAsync(async (doc) => {
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me (using Mongoose 6.3 on a ver 5.x MongoDB server) in 2022. According to [their latest documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregationcursor.html#aggregationcursor_AggregationCursor-Symbol.asyncIterator) this is what you have to do, and you don't need to chain `.exec()` onto it anymore:

```js
const pipeline = [{...}, {...}]; // aggregate stages go here
const cursor = Collection.aggregate(pipeline).cursor();

// cursor.next() method call
let doc;
while ((doc = await cursor.next())) {
    console.dir(doc);
}
```